# Nuget dependency resolution against dynamic assemblies loading

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm in the middle of migrating to nuget and I've encountered the following issue:
I have three projects A,B,C and A is dependent on B and C and B is dependent on C:

1. A => B,C
2. B => C

Project C

```
public interface IStartable
{
}
public interface IInterface
{
}
```

Project B

```
public abstract class StartableBase<T> : IStartable<T> where T : IInterface
{
}
```

Project A

```
public class InterfaceImpl : IInterface
{
}

public class StartableClass : StartableBase<InterfaceImpl>
{

}
```

Project C is loading assemblies dynamically on startup.

Now let's imagine following situation:

There are two versions of C - 1.0 and 2.0
I forgot to update project C in project B so it's still referencing 1.0.
Project C has updated its references so it references project B and C v2.0.
When project C tries to load assemblies it gets the message:

> GenericArguments[0], 'InterfaceImpl', on 'StartableBase`1[T]' violates
>   the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

It happens because StartableBase is expecting 1.0 `IInterface` implementation but it gets 2.0 `IInterface` implementation. There is a mismatch between C project versions.

What I've done:
I added project C to be dependency of project B so whenever I do `nuget pack` it will contain C as a dependency. Nevertheless this doesn't solve the issue in the above situation. Why? Because the default situation for nuget is to include dependencies with the version `upper or equal` than the current dependency version so in the above situation it will contain dependency to C v1.0 and project A will be able to include C version 2.0. Is there a way to say `nuget pack` to include exactly the same dependency versions? 
Remember that this situation is just for simplicity - everything is done on TeamCity automatically.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to say nuget pack to include exactly the same dependency versions?*

Yes, there is:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning

In your case, you can specify version `<dependency id="C" version="[1.0,2.0)" />` in your B.nuspec file.

So, if you are strict about semantic versioning your libraries (this is crucial, or you'll get yourself in trouble, so use it) you can update C to a new major when you break something, and your dependency in B will make sure to block updates to latest C in your A project.

Comment: Yes but remember that I don't specify dependencies versions hardcoded. Dependencies are resolved by nuget pack automatically and version is generated on teamcity. So ideally the solution I am looking for is:
<dependency id="C" version="[*]" />

Comment: AFAICT, the point is exactly that: you are making use of the AUTOMATIC resolution of nuget pack. But that is not enough, because your C package has breaking changes. So you cannot just tell nuget "do as you wish". But you, and only you, have to guarantee the compatibility for your dependencies. You do that in your nuspec file, which should be committed and your nuget pack command is going to  use during packaging. Am I missing something?

Comment: Everything is done on TeamCity. The project C 2.0 is released and triggers B build. Project  B updates dependencies so B version 1.1 will have dependency on C >= 2.0. If I want to use it in project A I will be able to update only C project and C == 2.0 without updating to project B 1.1.
Which means that it's possible to reference project B v1.0 and project C 2.0 and I want to prevent doing it because they are not compatible. It happens because B 1.0 doesn't complain about C 2.0 because previous version of B allows for newer versions of C. It should be one to one mappings between these two.

Comment: I cannot specify dependency version in a nuspec file because I don't do it manually. I can one additional step in TeamCity and do it using some scripts but I want to avoid it. There should be an automatic way to do it

Comment: I don't know Teamcity well enough to warrant you about that, but I want to point out that the nuspec is part of your codebase, anc not an automatic artifact. You are relying about the "good enough" quality of an auto generated nuspec file, but you just hit the complexity level when autogenerated nuspec is not good enough anymore. Just do a nuget spec on your machine and commit the nuspec file with the rest of the code. Just my 2c.

Comment: I do use nuspec file but I don't specify dependency because I don't want to use hardcoded version of C project. I always want to use the latest possible.

Comment: You always want to use the latest? But isn't your question about latest version breaking the build? The point is, how does B guarantees to NOT update C to latest, if that breaks the build. You can (maybe) look into the IncludeReferencedProjects option of the command line, which basically does the versioning of a referenced PROJECT (not package) for you. Maybe you can get away with that, if you build all the packages in the same environment, so you can guarantee that C gets built and B references the same version (at least, the same version) contained in the source code.

Comment: IncludeReferencedProjects is not an option because it's not in the same solution. 
As you can see from the example it's versioning issue and it doesn't break the build but it throws an exception in the runtime. I always want to use the latest C dependency in B project. In addition in project A when I reference project B it should FORCE me to use specific version of project C

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114930/discussion-between-a-chiesa-and-zbigniew).

Comment: Sorry, I can't join - it's blocked by company

Comment: Did you try to use bindingredirect? Does it solve your problem?
As far as I can tell, you have a chicken and egg problem.
When you update C and release it, you are creating a new version of C only (let's say v 2.0), which will break when used in conjunction with an old B. Right?

Comment: yes, that's it. I am not sure how binding redirects would handle that because where would I set that? In project B or project A?

Comment: Project A, in case. But the point is that your B.dll DOES NOT SUPPORT C 2.0. So, either you always update B too, when building C, and keep both synced, or you will always have this problem. B is broken when used with C latest. So, either you accept the sad truth that you have to check by yourself if B supports C latest, or you keep versioning B and C in sync.

Comment: Yes I wanted to limit "manual" work as much as I can. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Well, it's less work than you think. You just have to update the nuspec for major C releases. I don't know about you release cycles, but it shouldn't be too much hassle.